# Can birt support reading html tables from database and displaying them dynamically to a pdf report file?

Tags: crystal-reports, jasper-reports, birt

I have come across a scenario where I have to read html data from database and display it in pdf reports. This html data also contains table structure  `<table></table>` tags and other html element inside it. Previously we used jasper reports for our reporting needs but recently as we came to know that the above functionality is not supported in jasper, I wanted to know which reporting tool can be used so that it can be incorporated with servoy. Does birt provide this functionality?

Comment: there is a html component in jasper report (creates an image) so theoretically you can render html content

Comment: @PetterFriberg: We tried this option. It renders the html table from input. But it doesn't adjust its size according to the table that is being read. Now we are looking for other suitable reporting tools that can perform this well.

Comment: Thats why add.. creates an image, but I have done similar operation (maybe simpler than yours, the html structure was knowed before rendering) using jsoup (parse the html) and then dynamic jasper (to generate the report part to include), hence dynamic jasper generated the different jasper element for the table parsed by jsoup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, BIRT has a text element where we can set the display type to HTML. If the html table is in a dataset field you will just have to include it in the expression of the text using "value-of" tag, something like this:

```
<VALUE-OF format="HTML">row["htmlTableField"]</VALUE-OF>
```

PDF format is taking such html elements into account, including most of simple style settings such background color, text-align, borders etc.

[image]

Comment: While there isn't some kind of "officially supported" HTML elements list for BIRT, tables (which were explicitly mentioned in the question) are not really supported. They only work insofar as the underlying iText PDF engine has some rudimentary support built in, but this is hardly usable. I tried this myself and was quite disappointed.

Comment: Though it worked  out for my test data, I will keep that in mind what you said above.

Comment: @Dominique:what makes it hardly usable? Can you let me know what can happen if I start using it for larger data-sets?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK none of the well-known reporting tools does support this, although in BIRT it works "somehow" - but not good enough to be usable.
The reason for this is simple, I think: A reporting tool would have to incorporate a complete browser engine like WebKit or others to achieve this, because it would have to "understand" the structure for its page-breaking algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I need some redirection if possible to make the above task work out. May be looking for an entirely different platform?

Comment: This is the point at where I personally would give up and say it's impossible to do - at least for production quality code. You might try to skip all those reporting tools and create the whole report layout dynamically in pure HTML, though, using any tool you like (this is the easy part) and then *remote-control an actual browser program* like Chrome or Firefox to do the rendering, page-separation and PDF-creation. This is the more complicated part and I don't have an idea how to accomplish this. Since the browsers are open-source nowadays, it is at least theoretically possible...

Answer (score -4):

Usually the reports render just fine with html.

There are some tricks to displaying html correctly in BIRT.

You may use a [Dynamic Text](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.birt.doc%2Fbirt%2Ftxt-HowToUseADynamicTextElement.html) element and set to html or auto.

Here are some tricks to handling free form text..

Make sure your xml is valid, I recommend replacing line breaks or you may catch a scenario where the rptdocument will not export.

Also, if possible keep these in auto layout, when using run + render. The page breaks may actually be calculated once on run and again on render. You might experience breaking issues with fixed. The page may attempt to display all the html prior to breaking a page when using the RUN() phase, in web viewer or the rptdocument. Then when rendering to pdf the the breaks are applied differently, with fixed layout.

Comment: I realize your business is important, but unfortunately, this isn't the right place to promote your services. If you'd like, consider editing your user profile to add this information in. Please see the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) for more information.

Comment: @CullenBond No need to get upset; I was just advising you about one of  our rules.  See [What kind of behavior is expected of our users?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior), specifically the section "Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings."

Comment: We don't allow taglines here. Ask on meta if you'd like to dispute that policy.